# Issue with compiling GLUT with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, glut

I need to use GLUT (I know GLUT is an ancient library) for a project. When I run the project I get undefined references errors. This is my CMake file:

```
// Other code 
# GLUT
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${GLUT_DIR}/include")
if(GLUT_FOUND)
    message("-- GLUT found")
endif(GLUT_FOUND)

# OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${OpenGL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${OpenGL_DEFINITIONS})
if(OPENGL_FOUND)
    message("-- OPENGL found")
endif(OPENGL_FOUND)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARIES})
```

When I reload the CMake project I get the messages "-- GLUT found" and "-- OPENGL found" so finding the libraries is not the problem.
[image of cmake messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEMqE.png)
When running my project I get undefined references errors:
[image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO7YH.png)
I have looked at similair questions on stackoverflow but the solutions provided do not work in my case.
This is my file structure:
[image of my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwLbE.png)

Does anybody know a possible solution?

Comment: Showing the _actual_ errors is 1000 times more useful than describing the fact that you get "errors".

Comment: `add_library("glut" "${GLUT_DIR}/glut32.lib" "${GLUT_DIR}/glut.h")` seems odd. `find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)` should have pulled in the targets for GLUT

Comment: You're right. I probably added that in search of the solution to my problem. I am affraid it was not the root of the problem. I still get the same errors

Comment: You may want to add MESSAGE(STATUS GLUT_LIBRARIES="${GLUT_LIBRARIES}")  before the target_link_libraries() of your CMakeLists.txt and see what the output is during a cmake configure

Comment: @ids: Stack Overflow discourages using **images** for represent *text*. Instead, paste the text (error messages in your case) into the question post. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

**Always link via the imported targets.** Quit expanding package variables into directory-level commands. It's brittle and messy and more work.

Here's a basic example of linking to GLUT + OpenGL:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(example)

find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE GLUT::GLUT OpenGL::GL)
```

This pattern of `find_package` + `target_link_libraries` with an imported target is all that is needed for a majority of CMake-ready libraries.